# Can I suppress the styling the Intel XDK provides for af.ui.css?

Tags: intel-xdk

Is there an easy way to disable the styling provided by the Intel XDK? Specifically from af.ui.css.

The styling causes problems, especially when you are using external libraries. It would be nice to do something like jQuery Mobile's `data-role='none'`

e.g. I am trying to use a CSS style for star rating where the user can rate by touching or clicking on stars. This works fine on a normal HTML JavaScript page but somehow the af.ui.css gives one of the elements a width of 60%. These are the lines from af.ui.css which do that:

```
 #afui input[type="radio"] + label,
 #afui input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

This is the HTML it is acting on:

```
<label for="Ans_1" class="star rb0l" onclick=""></label>
```

If I comment the width statement in af.ui.css, it messes up other checkboxes. I tried to force a width in the label by using at style="width:.." but that doesn't work either.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Without more code structure it is hard to know exactly what could be going wrong.

In general if you use style="width:..." it should override afui.ui.css unless the css is being loaded after your inline styles and clobbers them. You can try to force your css style by using CSS '!important'
    .star {
    width: 20px !important; 
    }
either in an external CSS file or in style tags in your html file that load after the afui.ui.css file. You could even try style="width: 20px !important;". Some more info on this: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

In general I would use images or css for a star rating not checkbox or radio buttons. Here is a good example: http://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/

Let me know if that works for you or if you could include a screenshot or more html structure I can try to help.

You should be able to create your own id and then as long as you apply your styles after afui.ui.css is loaded it should keep the app framework styles but only override your star checkbox.

html file:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app_framework/2.1/css/af.ui.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <label id="idname"></label>
</body>
<style>
#afui input[type="checkbox"] + label + #idname {
   width: 20px;
}
</style>
```

OR...

html file:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app_framework/2.1/css/af.ui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="star.css">
</head>
<body>
  <label id="idname"></label>
</body>
```

star css file:

```
#afui input[type="checkbox"] + label + #idname {
   width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have shifted to working with the XDK but without af.ui.css. 
The sample that you gave me has a problem on the dabble where the stars dont get selected.
The problem with overwriting it as a style is that it clobbers other control on the same page which I want to avoid. 
And yes, af.ui.css for some reason over-rides inline styles.